# how to get the penultimate element?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

please help using xpath to get the content of the second tag . below is the code I wrote. but it does not work

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring("""
    <nav class="Paging">
            <a href="/women/dresses/cat/4?page=1" class="active">1</a>
            <a href="/women/dresses/cat/4?page=2">2</a>
            <a href="/women/dresses/cat/4?page=2" rel="next">Next »</a>
    </nav>
""")
res = doc.xpath('//nav[@class="Paging"][position() = 1]/a[position() = last() and @rel != "next"]/text()')

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You current expression does not work because `a[position() = last() and @rel != "next"]` tries to match the last element *if* its `rel` attribute is different from `"next"`. That is not the case in your markup, so the expression matches nothing.

You can just compare `position()` against `last() - 1` instead:

```
res = doc.xpath('//nav[@class = "Paging" and position() = 1]'
    + '/a[position() = last() - 1]/text()')
```

Comment: the problem is that the element <a href="/women/dresses/cat/4?page=2" rel="next">Next »</a>  can not be

Answer (score 0):

you can try the xpath:

```
//nav[@class="Paging"][position() = 1]/a[position() = last() - 1][not(@rel)]/text()
```